# launch applet from web page

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, applet

is it possible to launch an applet using webpage by clicking on link/button. I mean onclick of  link/button, i want to launch an applet, which shouldn't be embedded with the webpage. It should launch outside the webpage. Thanks in advance !!

using javascript i did this thing, but i want it like popup msgbox.

```
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
    function showApplet()
    {
    var attributes = {code:'myform.form.class',
                      archive:'applet.jar',
                      width:710, height:540} ;
    var parameters = {fontSize:16} ;
    var version = '1.6' ;
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
}
</script>
 <button onclick="javascript:showApplet()" value="Show" ></button>
```

Comment: You can do this by modifying the DOM of the page when the button is clicked. I would recommend jQuery for this.

Comment: For jQuery? Sure, here you go - http://jquery.com/.

Comment: Once you've come over to launching the applet using JWS, look into converting it to a frame and launching the frame with JWS (nicer end effect).

Comment: *"popup msgbox"*  What does that mean to you?  I understand pop-up, but the 'msgbox' is a bit less clear.  Do you mean like a pop-up window with no address bar and scroll bars (e.g. a [chromeless browser window](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex8/chromeless.htm))?  Do you mean inside a [JS 'alert'](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jalert.htm)?

Comment: i mean, it should appear like jquery modal popup

Answer (score 1):

Launch the applet using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  Since the Plug-In 2 architecture, JWS applets could be embedded.  But they could be launched free-floating since JWS was introduced.

Comment: but, i want to launch it as msgbox. i mean whenever i click on button applet popup.