# launching java applet

Tags: java, applet

As far as I can see from the documentation, `<applet>` is deprecated, and the `<object>` tag is the preferred method for launching an applet now.  But I can't find decent documentation, or even a tutorial on how to use the object tag to launch an applet.

I did see the following question which shows how in javascript but I would prefer to use a tag
[launch applet from web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343475/launch-applet-from-web-page)

I need to know how to specify the java engine, how to specify a jar file, where it's stored, and how to specify the class that is executed.

Here's what i have at the moment (but does not work)

```
<object
   classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"
   width="800" height="600" data="pi.jar">
    <param name="code" value="PiLauncher.class"/>
</object>
```

the claim was in the Oracle 1.5 docs that this classid specifies "the current java engine" but this is completely opaque to me.  They also had examples requesting a specific version.

Even if this is true, how do I:

1. specify the jar file
2. specify the class (is this correct above)
3. specify the directory where the code is (is codebase still valid?)

Comment: Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/using_tags.html)

Comment: *"but I would prefer to use a tag"*  Why?  Getting the correct string to embed an applet (in a particular version of a particular browser on a particular OS) is a PITA.  Better to delegate it to JS.

Comment: I stand corrected.  After looking at the answer below, I'm thoroughly disgusted.  This is something that should be standardized.  I can understand Microsoft doing something different, but everyone else ought to be able to agree.  For that matter, it should have been Oracle/Sun/java consortium stating an "official" way to do it.  UGH!

Comment: *"it should have been Oracle/Sun/java consortium stating an "official" way to do it."* One of my pet peeves in regard to applets is that Sun never bothered to define what *should* happen to focus when there were applets in a page (does the HTML link get the focus, or the applet text field?) nor implemented a way for an applet to accept focus into itself, then relinquish it gracefully back to the next HTML element.  This makes applets almost impossible to use without a mouse, and becomes a serious detriment to keyboard based navigation.  :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the syntax is not the same for firefox and IE:

Firefox:

```
<object classid="clsid:CAFEEFAC-0017-0000-0000-ABCDEFFEDCBA" id="appletId" name="appletName" width="400" height="300">
    <param name="code" value="com.myPackage.Applet" />
    <param name="codebase" value="../resources/applet/"/>
    <param name="ARCHIVE" value="myApplet.jar" />
    <param name="cache_archive" value="myApplet.jar" />
    <param name="type" value="application/x-java-applet" />
    <param name="cache_option" value="plugin" />
    <param name="mayscript" value="true" />
    // you can set optional parameters here 
</object>
```

IE:

```
<object width="400" height="300" classid="java:com.myPackage.Applet.class" codebase="../resources/applet/" name="appletName" id="appletId">
    <param name="archive" value="myApplet.jar" />
    <param name="type" value="application/x-java-applet" />
    <param name="cache_option" value="plugin" />
    <param name="mayscript" value="true" />
    // you can set optional parameters here         
</object>
```

Here is a good link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/using_tags.html#object

Comment: *"syntax is not the same for firefox and IE:"* Or Safari, ..or Opera, or Chrome, or..  Your basic point is correct, but it p1sses me off when developers assume that users use one of the 'big 2' apps in any field.  (+1 anyway.)

Comment: I should have completed: 'but I don't know how it works for other browsers'. But it's also relative.. the only time I used this was for a work in college so I didn't have to worry about users. Of course, if he is doing something public or comercial, you are totally right. :)

Comment: wow, this is really, really awful.  I feel like downchecking the answer because I hate it....

Comment: (scratches head)  If you 'shoot the messenger' it will make people only tell you what they think you *want* to hear.